# Formula of Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question like this:

> If $A + B + C = 90°$ then find $\sin \frac{B + C}{2}$

I try to make it start from this part:

$B = 90° - A - C$, 
$C = 90° - B - A$

Then substitute both of it, and ended up in this answer:

$\frac{2^{1/2}}{2} \ast \frac{(1+\cos A)^{1/2}}{2} - \frac{1-\cos A}{2}$

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: paul can u help me to solve this one ?

Comment: The question is not clear at all.

Comment: I think the question **is** clear. As the OP states, the problem is to find (a simpler, or alternative expression for) the quantity $\sin\frac{B+C}{2}$. The attempted solution is a mystery (to me), but the question is quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin \frac{B+C}{2} = \sin \frac{90° -A}{2} = \sin{(45° - \frac{A}{2}} )$.

Then use the formula for $\sin(A-B)=\sin A \cos B - \cos A \sin B$.

$\sin{(45° - \frac{A}{2}}) = \sin 45° \cos\frac{A}{2} - \cos45° \sin\frac{A}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\cos\frac{A}{2} - \sin\frac{A}{2}).$

Comment: yeahh i already arrive a this part Sin 45 cos A/2 - Cos 45 Sin A/2 any suggestion what next ?

Comment: i already got an answer like that, the problem is, i can't find my answer in the option, the option are
cos(A/2)
-cos(A/2)
sin(A/2)
-sin(A/2)
sec(A/2)
any suggestion ?

Comment: Options are **not** clear. Please write it clearly.

Comment: A. cos(A/2)
B. -cos(A/2)
C. sin(A/2)
D. -sin(A/2)
E. sec(A/2)

Comment: Sorry, $\color{#c00}{\text{none}}$ of them are correct. Kindly, check the question: Is it $A+B+C = \color{#0c0}{180^\circ}$? If yes, then option **A** is correct.

Comment: no actually the option B and D have a min on it

Comment: alright then :-) thanks for helping me :-)

Comment: Btw where can i learn math formating ?

Comment: nope..... it's A + B + C = 90

Comment: maybe wrong question :-)

Comment: @Mordekhai Search google with *How to learn latex* or even better, *How to learn latex math mode*.

Comment: @Mordekhai Sorry for so late response... You may like to visit this page: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 0):

$B + C = 90° - A$

$\implies \sin[(90^\circ - A)/2] = \sin(45^\circ - A/2) =(Simpson's formula)= \sin45^\circ\cos(A/2) - \cos45^\circ \sin(A/2) 
= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} [\cos(A/2) - \sin(A/2)]
$

Help?

Comment: i'm still newbie in this website don't know how to use math formatting and sorry for my bad english

Comment: alright :-) gonna try it  i guess

Answer (score 0):

in the question as formulated there is no constraint on $B+C$ (except that if the angles are positive, then $0 \le B+C \le \frac{\pi}2$)